# SUPEE 11219 not available for 1.9.2.x

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I have noticed that the latest SUPEE 11219 is not available for Magento 1.9.2.x via Magento you can only download for 1.9.3 and up, even thought the affected versions are Magento Open Source prior to 1.9.4.3

Do I see this incorrectly or what should be done in this case?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: All of the vulnerabilities in the list depend on attacker having access to the admin site. Lock it down and you should be fine until they release the patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Release of SUPEE-11219 for 1.9.2.x and older versions is delayed due to some porting issues. According to @piotrekkaminski we should expect it next week or so:
[twitter](https://twitter.com/piotrekkaminski/status/1185089895565529089)

UPDATE: SUPEE-11219 has been released now for 1.9.x.

Comment: thanks for sharing that information :)

Comment: Btw, SUPEE-11219 has been released now for 1.9.x.

Comment: According to [Twitter](https://twitter.com/piotrekkaminski/status/1190250042025750528) "earlier versions" (like 1.8) should receive patch soon. However, it's not yet [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/#download2330).

Comment: Also 1.6.0 - 1.8.1 seems to be [released](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/#download2330) now.